# Why does Elasticsearch Cluster JVM Memory Pressure keep increasing?

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm, aws-elasticsearch

The JVM Memory Pressure of my AWS Elasticsearch cluster has been increasing consistently. The pattern I see for the last 3 days is that it adds 1.1% every 1 hour. This is for one of the 3 master nodes I have provisioned.

All other metrics seem to be in the normal range. The CPU is under 10% and there are barely any indexing or search operations being performed.

I have tried clearing the cache for `fielddata` for all indices as mentioned in [this document](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/high-jvm-memory-pressure-elasticsearch/) but that has not helped.

Can anyone help me understand what might be the reason for this?

[image: Step Pattern]

Comment: Ideally this should not happen when there is no activity on the cluster. Can you double check and see if any of this from https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/high-jvm-memory-pressure-elasticsearch/ causing the leak. If nothing helps then you need to talk to AWS Support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got this answer from AWS Support

> I checked the particular metric and can also see the JVM increasing from the last few days. However, I do not think this is an issue as JVM is expected to increase over time. Also, the garbage collection in ES runs once the JVM reaches 75% (currently its around 69%), after which you would see a drop in the JVM metric of your cluster. If JVM is being continuously > 75 % and not coming down after GC's is a problem and should be investigated.
>
> The other thing which you mentioned about clearing the cache for
> fielddata for all indices was not helping in  reducing JVM, that is
> because the dedicated master nodes do not hold any indices data and
> their related caches. Clearing caches should help in reducing JVM on
> the data nodes.